# Error -::Type 'string | Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in my React application (TypeScript based).

I am using it like this:

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:  faq.answer  }}/>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Type 'string | Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[image]

is there any way to fix this?

I am getting HTML from server like this `<p>hello</p>`. My output is correct. But while creating build my build breaks because we are doing typechecking before build.

Comment: Well what _do_ you expect to happen if `faq.answer` is an `Element`?

Comment: I am getting HTML from server like this `<p>hello</p>`. my output is correct. but while creating build my build break because we are doing typechecking before build

Comment: Well your type says it _won't_ always be a string like `"<p>hello</p>"`, so either your type is wrong or _you need to deal with that possibility_. We can't tell you how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided much detail, but, assuming you want to serialize `faq.answer` in the case that it's an element, you can use [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) like this:

```ts
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: typeof faq.answer === 'string'
  ? faq.answer
  : faq.answer.outerHTML }}/>
```